# Blackberry - single line BasicEditField with large text

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, custom-controls

I have created a customized BasicEditField with Border using Bitmap.Now while typing the text,it crosses the border of the `BasicEditField`.

This is my code

```
class customEditField1 extends EditField
{
     Bitmap mBorder = null;
     customEditField1(Bitmap borderBitmap) 
     {
        mBorder = borderBitmap;
     }
     protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
     {
         graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, mBorder.getWidth(),mBorder.getHeight(), mBorder, 0, 0);
         super.paint(graphics);
     }
}
```

I want to create a BasicEditField which should hide the previously entered text and displays the newly entered text and the typed text should be with in the border.It should not depends on the number of chars limit.And i want to Apply padding between the text and the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put BasicEditField into HorizontalFieldManager.
Don't forget to move border bitmap painting from BasicEditField to HorizontalFieldManager.

```
class ScrollEdit extends HorizontalFieldManager {
    Bitmap mBorder = null;
    public BasicEditField mEdit = null;

    public ScrollEdit(Bitmap border) {
        super(HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
        mBorder = border;
        mEdit = new EditField(BasicEditField.NO_NEWLINE);
        add(mEdit);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, mBorder.getWidth(), mBorder.getHeight(),
                mBorder, 0, 0);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }

}
```

But you will have to play around with layout and setExtent to size manager and edit correctly. My advice is to try it without border bitmap first.

See [Scroll BasicEditField instead of wrap](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=965)

Talking about the wrap, set padding to BasicEditField within manager or add white space in border bitmap...

Comment: I dont know how to move border bitmap from BasicEditField to HorizontalFieldManager?

Comment: Take a look at code provided, it's already there in paint(), I've just drown your attention to it.

Comment: @MaxGontar how can we set background images or Edittextield ?

Comment: @Coder afaik we can't set it, we have to draw it ourselves.